# How do I show english menus in german page tree where german is the default language with TYPO3?

Tags: typo3, typoscript

We have a TYPO3 9 LTS instance with German as default and English as secondary language. Now there are parts of the pagetree which do not have any German content, and we want to be able to set the language for those pages to English. The English content is put into the default language and not being translated for editorial convenience.

Previously the Site was based on TYPO3 7 LTS, and we had a static typoscript template that our lead editors could include as an Extension Template for the subtree to set the language to English.

```
 # use fix language parameters independent of the url
config.sys_language_uid = 1
config.language = en
config.htmlTag_langKey = en
config.locale_all = en_GB.UTF-8

 # ignore language setting to be able to reference both lang uid 0 and 1 content
config.sys_language_mode = ignore

 # hide the language menu
lib.topnav.language = TEXT
lib.topnav.language.value =
```

With TYPO3 9 LTS and site config based language handling the typoscript settings do not work. Main menu and navigation are shown in German. Is there a way to set the language to English with the site config, or typoscript? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: have you considered the 'fallback' option?

Comment: If I am not mistaken the fallback only works for non-default languages or am I missing something? Since the page always exists for the default language there is no check for when to fall back to another language.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to set the language of the contents in the default language to "all languages" (-1). This way the English translation can be empty but the contents from the default are shown.

This of course only works when the default content should be shown on every language.

It took some time to accept this solution since the editorial work needed was quite a lot with many affected pages and content.

Hope this helps.

Kind regards,
Jona